# cname/subdomain for redirect to query string?

Tags: dns, cname

I want to do something where I use a subdomain of my domain to redirect to a long query string.

So for example, if the end target was something like `www.example.com/info?user=johndoe&color=blue&type=premium`, is it possible to setup with something like `user.example.com`?

The query string is quiet long and so it is too big to cname.  I'd like to save hosting a file somewhere that redirects, it seems like something i might be able to do just using my dns registration, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use DNS to send HTTP redirects. You have to use an HTTP server to do that. Note that `CNAME` only gives you a domain name alias, so that `foo.example.org` resolves to the same IP address that `bar.example.org` does. Whatever web server is at that IP address is then responsible for deciding how to respond to the path that follows the domain name.